# What is the word for previous boss’s recommendations in the context of a CV?

Tags: word-choice

In my CV, I am trying to explain  that a written recommendation from my previous boss is available upon request.

What is that document called?

Comment: This is General (**Reference**).

Comment: Voting to close general reference: http://onelook.com/?w=written+recommendation+from+my+previous+boss&ls=a

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a [reference](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/reference) (see sense 3).

Answer (score 5):

In the UK, at least, it's known as a *reference*.

Comment: Attested further afield, also.